# open XML 2.5 cell value different from cell Formula result. Can i force value?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a service that reads financial information that belongs to different companies from an excel file **(File 1)** and produces several separated excel files out of it **(Files C1, C2, …. Cn)**, by copying a template **(File T1)** and writing into the copies using open xml 2.5 (lets call this one **service A**). After that I have the **service B**, which reads each excel produced by service A and stores the data individually.

Service A reads the input file (File 1) and, imagine cell C21 has a value of 10. 
Service A writes into the new file C1 which template already has a formula on cell C21 (C21 = C20 – C19) which gives a different result if calculated;

If you open the file C1 using MS Excel, it will contain the value of 10 on cell C21 and the formula C20-C19 that would give a different result if calculated. Let us call this **Scenario 1**.

I did not wanted that, so I forced the formula to be calculated as [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668643/openxml-sdk-make-excel-recalculate-formula) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012545/calculate-cell-values-from-formula-programmatically-in-openxml-sdk2) suggest:

```
spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true; 
spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;
```

So now, If you open the file using MS Excel it will contain the inner text as the result of the calculation of the formula **(Scenario 2)**, but still the value is 10. The **service B** still reads the same value for **scenario 1 and 2**.

**Scenario 3** – On the scenario 2, after opening the file using MS Excel, if you save it, the service B will read the file with the result of the calculation of the formula. The cell value is changed.

Is there any way to get the scenario 3 programmatically? In other words, if a Cell contains a value that differs from the result of the formula of the cell, can I force it to assume the formula?

If I open the xml structure of the excel files, this is what you get:

[image]

I am reading the excel files with the [MSDN approach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh298534.aspx) and I am also writing following [MSDN sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc861607.aspx)

Comment: Have you considered just dealing with your excel presentation with VBA instead of C#?  I find using OpenXml that keeping the C# strictly to text then writing a macro for `Auto_Open` to be a nice strategy.

Comment: Thanks. No, i haven't considered. The reading service is in production. If there isn't another way, i will consider. Thank you.